# Частица Не со словом "сильный"

Tags: частица-не

*Если обезболивающее помогло, то боль (не) сильная.*

Как пишется не со словом в данном случае?

Comment: *Если боль (не) сильная, то обезболивающее помогло*.  Разве не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Если обезболивающее помогло, то боль **несильная**.*

**Пояснение**

1. Многие прилагательные имеют **градационные ряды** признаков, например: *маленький — небольшой (почти маленький) — не большой и не маленький (средний) — большой*.
2. Но в **данном конкретном** случае градационный ряд, вероятно, выглядит так: *слабый —  несильный (ослабленный, не являющийся сильным) — сильный.*
3. Поэтому, если средство все-таки отчасти помогло, то боль **уже несильная** (не является сильной). (Конечно, желательно,чтобы боли вообще бы не было.)
4. Вариант "боль не сильная" мало о чем говорит, вряд ли такая перспектива устроит пациента.

Ну и уточняем по словарю: **НЕСИЛЬНЫЙ**,  Такой, который не является сильным. <Несильно, нареч.